# Saving layer as shapefile (shp)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-statistics, dbf, save

I'm trying several spatial statistics analysis in my QGIS 2.18.3 project (*convex hull, random points inside polygons, point sampling tool, basic statistics for numeric fields, distance matrix, nearest neighbour analysis, mean coordinates, polygon centroids*).

Since I used the *nearest neighbour analysis*, which is saved under a .html in my data folder, I cannot save any other layer as a **shapefile (shp)**. The proposed type of files are just **.dbf, .xlsx, .csv** and **.ods**.  Encoding is set as System. Pre-selected type of file is .dbf.

**Result is that mean coordinates and polygon centroids are not visualised in the project.**

I tried to create a *fix buffer* that I already did this morning and even that layer was not able to be saved under a shapefile, but in the morning it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with help from @tallistroan.

First, I saved the buffer as a temporary layer and then saved it as a shp.

After that, the action Save to file as a shp was again available for all the analysis output layers!